# Pointer position way off in Java Application menu's when using gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, 12.10, java, jdk

When using any java application in gnome-shell if the window is maximised the pointer position is way off; but only on the menu's, in the editor, or the side panel, the pointer is fine.

This only presents itself when the window is maximized, and it seems that the further away from 0x0 the window is when you maximise it, the bigger the pointer offset.

From what I have gathered it has to do with the window not updating it's size when it gets maximised.

The other issue is that when a gnome-shell notification appears, when clicking on it, I lose the ability to type in the editor, I can select text etc, but can't give it focus to type. I must bring up some other text input (e.g. right click on a file on the left, select rename, which brings up a rename dialog) after that I can type in the editor again.

So, how can I fix this?

Below is as much information as I can think to provide

[image: Pointer position offset]

[image]

> $ **gnome-shell --version**
> GNOME Shell 3.6.1
>
> $ **java -version**
> java version "1.7.0_09" Java(TM) SE Runtime
> Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
> (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
>
> $ **file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac**
> /etc/alternatives/java:  symbolic link to '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java'
> /etc/alternatives/javac: symbolic link to '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac'

Comment: if you get this problem fixed? i have the same problem.

Comment: jetbrains have implemented a fix in the eap version

Comment: I think this is a bug. And if not I would just say "Wow!". (I've seen this problem on MATLAB some releases back.) So you should file it where appropriate. According to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572934/java-swing-mouse-pointer-shifted-on-context-menu-when-jframe-is-maximized) the bug is not reproducible in Java 6, try switching to Java 6 if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in the EAP release of PHPstorm following this post, as far as I am aware a global fix was implemented with the upgraded java version.